# Does every metric satisfy translation invariance property $d(x+a,y+a)=d(x,y)$

Tags: metric-spaces

Is every metric translation invariant,if no then what are the conditions under which a metric may become translation invariant (if any) .

Comment: Plase say what is it that you mean by “translation invariant”. What is a translation in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: since every  metric induced by norm satisfy translation invariance property but i am confused about ,can we impose any condition on metrics so that they might satisfy translation invariance property

Comment: Again: what is it that you mean by “translation invariant”? Are interested only on metrics defined on vector spaces?

Comment: i mean d(x+a,y+a) = d(x,y)

Comment: And wha does $+a$ mean in an arbitrary metric space?

Comment: if we take X= |R^infinity ( R =real line) ,

Comment: I don't know what $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is, nor what it has to do with the complex plane.

Comment: Let V be a vector space. Is any metric d which satisfies d(u, v) = d(u + w, v + w) for all u, v, w in V necessarily induced by some norm on V?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if we are working on a vector space, the answer is negative. In $\mathbb R$, you can define the distance $d(x,y)=\bigl|x^3-y^3\bigr|$, which is not translation invariant: $d(1,0)=1$ and $d(1+1,1+0)=7\neq1$.